# GoogleSQL in BigQuery evaluating IF always True inside FOR-loop but False if manually checked

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Goodmorning everyone,

recently we started to use BigQuery in my current company to analyze an enormous amount of data (around 4TB) from a client.

Apparently a lot of columns in some table seems to be always Null, but since we are speaking of tables with more than 90 columns for something around 13 tables we tried to write down a function to get an Array of Columns with at least a Non-Null value, and then we'll create some views from the returned Array.

The SQL Script is the following:

```
DECLARE r ARRAY <STRING>;
SET r = []; 

FOR var IN (SELECT column_name FROM `project-name.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
  WHERE table_name LIKE "table_name") DO
    IF EXISTS(SELECT var.column_name FROM `project-name.dataset.table_name`
      WHERE var.column_name IS NOT NULL) THEN 
        SET r = ARRAY_CONCAT(r, [var.column_name]);
    END IF;
END FOR;

SELECT r;
```

I'm not quite fond of SQL, I'll be glad of any help, I've tried to follow the conventions and examples from the documentation of BigQuery

We tried to manually replicate the behaviour on a column with the following code, evaluating False returning 0:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT column_name FROM `project-name.dataset.table_name` WHERE column_name IS NOT NULL) THEN 
  SELECT 1;
ELSE
  SELECT 0;
END IF;
```

yet while executed inside the for loop seems to always evaluate as True.

Comment: Hi @zigb11 you should consider using Google Cloud Dataplex instead of using sql. See this documentation which allows you to run data quality scan across multiple tables https://cloud.google.com/dataplex/docs/use-auto-data-quality#create-scan and as well as using pre-defined rules for null checks, see the (Null check) rule in the documentation https://cloud.google.com/dataplex/docs/auto-data-quality-overview#predefined-rules

Answer (score 0):

1. Lets go to the definition of Exists in Big Query:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/subqueries#exists_subquery_concepts

Returns TRUE if the subquery produces **one or more rows.**

2. Now simple example in BQ

   CREATE TEMP TABLE test
   (
   id INT64,
   name STRING
   );

   INSERT INTO test
   VALUES (1, NULL);

   INSERT INTO test
   VALUES (2, NULL);

   INSERT INTO test
   VALUES (3, NULL);
3. I created temp table called 'test'
4. Added two columns: id, name
5. 'name' column contains only NULLS

Then let's do a simple trick

```
SELECT name FROM test
      WHERE test IS NOT NULL;
```

And then result will be

[image: Result]

Or if we apply EXISTS to the query:

[image: Result if we check EXISTS]

So, that's where's the problem hidden I believe. Hope this helps.